# How to enable multi-tenancy in Hibernate 4 with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

It looks to me as though [support for multi tenancy has been added to hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/commit/3ff0288da5f7d74f9fe964712a7ae869aee69bfd) for nearly six months now and [updated at least once since](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/commit/20064fa743cb3ec34e732d7fd6f5719d8b119ddf).

It looks fairly trivial to obtain a multi-tenant Session outside of JPA:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier( "jboss" ).openSession();
```

But how would you enable it in an application that uses hibernate via JPA? (If possible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your both links are not working. it will be great if you add them back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure it via properties in persistence.xml as follows:

```
<property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE"/>
<property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="com.example.MyConnectionProvider" />
<property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="com.example.MyTenantIdResolver" />
```

If you use SCHEMA as multi-tenancy strategy `hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider` is not needed.

You can also set these properties in your code and pass them in a map to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()`. In this case you can pass an object instance, not just a class name.

More info in [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html).

Answer (score 5):

[EntityManager.getDelegate()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getDelegate%28%29)  will return underlying `SessionImpl`.

Comment: that's not available for a sessionfactory though

Comment: `SessionImpl tmpsession = (SessionImpl) entityManager.getDelegate(); SessionFactory sessionFactory = tmpsession.getSessionFactory(); Session session = sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier( "jboss" ).openSession();`