# How do I execute JPA 2.1 Criteria queries with hibernate multi tenancy enabled

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I am using hibernate schema (one schema per tenant) based multitenancy as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html).
I want to execute the new JPA criteria queries (javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery) as described [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e3364) ?

```
List<Person> people = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

How do i get the correct EntityManager object to execute the query in the context of the appropriate tenant schema ?

Hibernate version 4.2

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255294/how-to-enable-multi-tenancy-in-hibernate-4-with-jpa